# Why do I get different answers when using the shell method and disc method?

Tags: calculus, volume

I've tried solving the following question two ways, and I got different results.

> Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region bounded by $y = \sqrt{x}$, $y = 0$, and $x = 9$ about the line $y = -2$.

**1. Disc Method**

We have that the spin axis is $-2$, therefore:

$$\int_0^9\pi(\sqrt{x}+2)^2\, dx = \frac{297}{2}\pi.$$

**2. Shell Method**

Since we are using the shell method that means, our width is $dy$. Solving for $x$ we have $x = y^2$ and now we find the intercepts by setting $y^2 = 9$, which are $3$ and $-3$. Therefore, we have 
$$\int_0^3 2\pi (9-y^2)(y+2)\, dy= \frac{225}{2}\pi.$$

I would like to know what I did wrong and how can I fix it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MyGlasses I'm rotating the curve around y = -2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the disk, you missed that you have a hole of radius $2$ in the middle of the disk.  That removes a cylinder of volume $\pi 2^2\cdot 9=36\pi$, which makes it agree with the shell method.